# Nginx basic auth issue

Tags: authentication, nginx, basic-authentication, nginx-location, nginx-config

I want to have a basic-auth in nginx configured for my application running on URL http://milesblock.com which automatically changes to http://milesblock.com/#/

Now, the issue is if I apply the basic auth for http://milesblock.com it gets applied to the next subsequent page as well and gets in an infinite loop asking for username and password and then nothing works.
My nginx.conf looks like this -

```
    server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  milesblock.com;


    location / {

       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
       auth_basic "Restricted Area";
       auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   }


   location /api1 {

        rewrite ^/api1(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

How do I configure the nginx so that only the main URL (http://milesblock.com) asks for the username and password only once ?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that you are entering the user and password correctly?

Comment: yes, the credentials are correct. But still it gets in the infinite loop getting the username/password popup.